# Range.Find produces error when find fails

Tags: excel, vba

These are two simple lines of code to find an instance of a 6 digit number in a list. If the number exists, everything works perfectly but if not, I get the error "Object variable or With block variable not set"

The lines of code are

```
    COL = Cells(5, "A").Text
    RowFound = Sheets("Master List").Columns("A").Find(What:=COL).Row
```

The cell format is Text in the column and in the search data cell

Any advice on this would be helpful and much appreciated

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find  Do the `Find` call first (without the extra Row) call. Test the result for `is Nothing` before trying to find the row. As per the example in the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way VBA works. VBA cannot return a row from a not existing range.

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub testFindFail()
  Dim c As Range, RowFound As Long, COL As String
  COL = cells(5, "A").text
  Set c = Sheets("Master List").Columns("A").Find(What:=COL) 'it will be good to also use some other parameters.
  If c Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'or do something else
  RowFound = c.row
  Debug.Print RowFound
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for that. I had tried trapping the error using Nothing but hadn't realised that I should test with IS - Nothing being a nul object - rather than "=". OK now...

Comment: @Keith Marwood Glad I could help! But we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue, will know that the code works...

Comment: Done, FaneDuru. Many thanks. I have done lots of Delphi Pascal programming, so I will try to help someone else, if I ever can...